# Why discord bot works with default emojis and when i put custom emojis doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I was making music commands. In the code before i put default discord emojis and worked, but now i put emojis i added and doesnt work.

A part of the code

```
await playingMessage.react("<:sh_skip:799324187004239933>");
```

and below

```
case "<:sh_skip:799324187004239933>":
      queue.playing = true;
      reaction.users.remove(user).catch(console.error);
      if (!canModifyQueue(member)) return;
      queue.connection.dispatcher.end();
      queue.textChannel.send(`<:sh_skip:799324187004239933> Skipped the song!`).catch(console.error);
      collector.stop();
      break;
```

Where i put the <:sh_skip... before there was a default emoji and worked, but now i changed it to look better and when i react to the message it removes my reaction but it doesn't do the function

Comment: I'd get the ID of the emoji and just compare that instead

Answer (score 1):

I think part of your problem could be using " rather than `  so try changing that. That could still not work, in which case, you can send them like this:

```
const emoji = client.emojis.cache.get('emoji-id');
await playingMessage.react(emoji);
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem was that before i start the case, i told the bot to switch reaction.emoji.name, and i was putting the whole emoji code instead of the emoji name.

So if someone has this problem, in the await part put the emoji code, but in the code put just the emoji name ( <:sh_skip:799392380750659604> and sh_skip )